# why FieldValue.serverTimestamp() return null value from first snapshot

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have the following write

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").doc(widget.userId).set({
  "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

and when i read the previous doc using `StreaBuilder widget` it do return null value from the first snapshot `data['timestamp']`

when i use `DateTime().now` instead of  `FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),` it do perfect job
but that does not fit my case

i read many question similar mine but there no useful answer .
i can't understand why it return null ..

i also tried the following in `UI` but i need good way

```
`data['timestamp']`!= null ? `data['timestamp']` : '',
```

outputs result with delay 2 sec .. also this way can be work with UI only but not in case i use listen Method instead of `StreamBuilder` out of UI scope

i can't understand this ..

***EDIT***

here is my listen method that read data once write operation is done

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").doc(widget.userId).snapshots().listen((val) async{  
    print(val.get['timestamp']);// here will outputs null value from only first snapshot.
```

Note: I have others fields too in the same doc, and the listener does outputs them all successfully except `val.get['timestamp']` => null like following

```
print(val.get['name']);; // successfully result
print(val.get['age']);; // successfully result
print(val.get['product']);; // successfully result
print(val.get['timestamp']); // failed operation (from first snapshot)
```

But if i use `DateTime.now()` instead `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` it works.

Comment: I think you're likely seeing the initial, local value for the field, but it's hard to be certain as we don't see how you're reading the data. Can you edit your question to show the minimal code that reads from the database with which you get the `null` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to determine the value of the `timestamp` field, the value of that field won't be known until the document is written on the server.

Since you listen to the `snapshots()` stream, you will immediately get an event for the local write operation **before it is sent to the server**.

So since the initial event on the `snapshots()` stream happens before the operation is sent to the server, the value of `timestamp` is not known yet, and this reading that field will result in `null`.

You will need to handle this in your code, either by rendering no value for the `timestamp` at that point, or to render an estimate, for example the current **local** data/time.